# Win32 - A better way to intercept a window before it is created

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to automate an external Windows application. The goal is to make this application start minimized without showing any active window/splash screens and without stealing focus from other applications.

I wrote a little program on C that calls EnumWindows() in a loop and uses ShowWindow() to minimize the required window. It is quite fast and works in 80% of cases. Unfortunately, sometimes the application window is still showing and stealing the focus for a short period of time.

What would be a better (sure) way to intercept the window?
Is using SetWindowsHookEx hooks the only alternative?

Comment: I don't suppose the external app can be automated with COM?

Comment: No, it is a .NET application and I have not much documentation about it.

Comment: You could use [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) to get notifications about window creation. Listening for [`EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) events will provide this information. What's more, it gives you access to automation interfaces, that you need for automation anyway. Whichever way you go about it, be warned that automating applications that do not expose a dedicated automation interface is very brittle.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `wShowWindow` member of the [`STARTUPINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you pass to [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when starting the application?  That was designed to do exactly things like this.

> If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, this member can be any of the values that can be specified in the nCmdShow parameter for the ShowWindow function, except for SW_SHOWDEFAULT. Otherwise, this member is ignored.
>
> For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow parameter is ignored wShowWindow specifies the default value. In subsequent calls to ShowWindow, the wShowWindow member is used if the nCmdShow parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.

For example:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) }
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;

CreateProcess(..., &si, ...);
```

Comment: It is designed for this, but the caveat is that some applications ignore it, or apply the setting to the main window but show a splash screen first anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the case. The application seems to ignore the window state specified at launching. So the method above does not work as well as launching from the command prompt via START "" /MIN APP.EXE.